# Apache Camel: Discarding Split Processors When Complete

Tags: java, multithreading, split, apache-camel

I am using the Camel Split component with parallel processing to split an ArrayList of integers.  The List has 700,000+ IDs in it.  The idea is that each ID needs to be passed to an XML generator and then inserted into a database table.  However, I've noticed that it appears that the XML that gets generated and passed back to Camel in the message body is held on to.  It looks like it hold onto the message body until all elements in the Split have completed processing.  That means that I would have 700,000+ XMLs in memory.  Is there a way to tell Camel to not do this?  To discard the Split worker when it completes its work?

I have tried making chunks of IDs and splitting each chunk, allowing the split to complete and the memory to be freed.  The issue here is that each ID generates XMLs of varying sizes.  Thus, if I make chunks of 10 IDs and 1 of those has a very large XML associated to it, my thread pool has to wait for the largest one to complete and I end up with 9 idle threads.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Splitter EIP reference on Streambased splitting](https://camel.apache.org/splitter.html#Splitter-Streambased)? It seems directly connected to your question. You may have better luck using the `streaming()` invocation and perhaps a custom aggregator

I'd hazard that you are experiencing the default behavior of the splitter's aggregator, which takes all the "replies" from whatever processors you passed the split messages to, and joins them all back together again to pass on as a single "response" from the splitter processor to the next processor in your route. Hence the large XML payload in memory.

If you write a custom aggregator, you could instead just record a count of messages marshalled and persisted, and have that passed on as the "response" from the splitter, which should explicitly release the XML payloads from memory. I'd give a clearer example but my Camel is pretty rusty these days.

I hope I've left enough breadcrumbs here to be of help. Largely, look at the document I linked to at the top of this answer, there are a number of great samples that seem to apply to your use case either directly or nearly so.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Actually, I'm already using the streaming option.  I'm looking into the custom aggregation, was just hoping there might be some out of the box magic, as that seems to be what Camel is best at.

Comment: It's been a while since I used the splitter, but I recall similar pains. It has to do with camel's processor-based pattern, and a splitter as a whole is considered a single processor, so it expects to construct a single output. This can cause considerable consternation when you really want it to dispatch discrete messages and not aggregate the results for you auto-magically.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know, if this is best practice, but if the body content is not needed any more, you could just define a `Processor` that empties the body as follows:

```
 public class EmptyProcessor implements Processor {
     @Override
     public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
         exchange.getIn().setBody(null);
     }
 }
```

Furthermore, you could handle the single splits in parallel, so that long lasting jobs do not block the processing.

Example route:

```
final Random random = new Random(3);

from("direct:start")
    .split().method(Splitter.class, "split")  // the splitter creates the Integer list
    .parallelProcessing()
    .executorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            final long waitMs = (long) (random.nextFloat() * 1000);
            System.out.println("Doing a long lasting job for " + waitMs + " ms");
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        }
    })
    .process(new EmptyProcessor())
    .log("Body (should be emtpy): ${body}");
```